# Prolog: Simple DCG a^n b^n

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

I've been trying to get used to using DCGs in Prolog and failing.

How can I define a set of grammar rules to accept the language a^n b^n?

E.g. aaaabbbb or ab etc...

Thanks :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ab --> [].
ab --> [a], ab, [b].
```

Comment: Thank you.  With your rules, it accepts ab([a,a,a,b,b,b],[]). like I would expect but is there any good way of making it accept ab(aaabbb,[]). other than exploding aaabbb into [a,a,a,b,b,b] using an auxilary predicate?  Thank you :).

Comment: You'll have to explode it into a list. DCGs don't work on atoms.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers, you're helped me a lot with Prolog :).  It was just DCGs I was battling with mostly.  Thanks :).